# Advanced Installer: Show preview Pictures for every Feature

Tags: advanced-installer, getpicture

**First Question:**

Is it possible to show the Users preview Pictures for every Feature?
If they go with the mouse on the Feature I want to have a description
and a preview Picture from the elements to install!

For example: for a Game different Modifications!

I can't find this function in the Installer and I think I have searched a lot!

**And second question:**

Is it possible to disable the "advanced Installer" inscription on every Installer side?

Answer (score 0):

1) The standard MSI controls do not support this kind of user interaction. However, [Advanced Installer does have an UI theme for the dialogs where you can use HTML and JS](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-new-dialog-spring-theme.html) to render a custom UI for the end users. You could try use that.

2) Yes, but only if you have a license for the Enterprise or Architect edition. You can customize your dialogs in any way you desire, from Dialogs page.

The same license is also required to try to the solution from the first question.

With the trial version of Advanced Installer you can use any of these feature for 30 days, for free.